# How can I get image properties like scaleX in react-kova?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

Like the example shown for shape, this has x,y,rotation etc. https://konvajs.github.io/docs/select_and_transform/Transform_Events.html

Image in react-konva also extends shape.

How can I get these values for image(with transformer) in react-konva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen `transform` event and then read all properties from the image node.

```
  handleTransform = () => {
    const props = {
      x: this.image.x(),
      y: this.image.y(),
      rotatio: this.image.rotation(),
      width: this.image.width(),
      height: this.image.height(),
      scaleX: this.image.scaleX(),
      scaleY: this.image.scaleY()
    };
    console.log(props);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Image
            image={this.state.image}
            ref={node => {
              this.image = node;
            }}
            draggable
            onTransform={this.handleTransform}
            onDragMove={this.handleTransform}
          />
          <Transformer
            ref={node => {
              this.transformer = node;
            }}
          />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wq184owy45

Comment: Hey there. I have been trying to implement this with React Hooks but failed to do so. Can you provide an example on how to transform an image? Should I create a new post?

Comment: @Zak you should

Comment: Hey man, here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368679/unable-to-add-transform-feature-with-react-hooks-using-konvajs . It would be helpful if you could provide a full example.

Comment: Hey Lavrton, I have updated that post of mine. Getting an infinite loop of images on the canvas staging area. Please check it.